# Windows: Stop users from deleting files NTFS

Tags: security, ntfs, window, shared-folders

I've changed the NTFS permissions on a folder called share1 that means users from group 'nodelete' do not have permissions 'delete' or 'delete subfolders and files'

This seemed to work OK, except one of my users just pointed out that any new content which is created in share1 can be delete afterwards. Upon checking the properties of a new text file that was created, the security tab contained a separate entry for that user and gave them all permissions.

Is there any method to block ownership of newly created files so users don't have the ability to delete files once created? Or is any other method to ensure users in the 'nodelete' group cannot delete any file in this folder?

Comment: Does "CREATER OWNER" exist in the ACL? did you disable inheritance?

Comment: CREATOR OWNER is still in the ACL but inheritance is disabled. Should creator owner be removed?

Comment: Yes it should be removed. Or remove the delete permission from creater.